# Two columns can not be null at the same time in sql

Tags: sql, constraints

Suppose there is a table called `Employee` with the fields:

```
ID number, 
name varchar(24 char), 
address varchar2(100 char), 
alternateAddress(100 char), 
sex varchar2(10 char)
```

Now I want to put a constraint such that both `address` and `alternateAddress` cannot be `null` i.e
possible cases are:

- `address` is null and `alternateAddress` is not `null`
- `alternateAddress` is `null` and `address` is not `null`
- `alternateAddress` is not `null` and address is not `null`

But what cannot happen is that any record in `Employee` table is inserted with `alternateAddress` and `address` both `null`.

Comment: please specify the RDBMS when asking questions like this e.g. MySQL, SQL-Server, Oracle, Postgres etc.

Answer (score 9):

Create a constraint to your table like this:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Employee]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [CK_OneAddress] CHECK  ((NOT [address] IS NULL) OR (NOT [alternateAddress] IS NULL))
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Employee] CHECK CONSTRAINT [CK_OneAddress]
GO
```

Comment: I used below sql script similar to what u have suggested and it works perfectly fine                                                ALTER TABLE Employee ADD  CONSTRAINT CK_OneAddress CHECK (NOT ((alternateAddress IS  NULL) AND (address IS NULL)));

Comment: No problem, regarding boolean algebra your script is equivalent to my suggestion. Would you please mark my answer as accepted? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Create your constraint like this:

```
(address is null and alternateAddress is not null) or 
(alternateAddress is null and address is not null) or 
(alternateAddress is not null and address is not null)
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you not use:

```
IF(COALESCE(address, alternateAddress) IS NOT NULL)
```

or

```
WHERE (COALESCE(address, alternateAddress) IS NOT NULL)
```

Or is that bad form?

Answer (score 0):

With De Morgan's Law, not (A and B) is equivalent to (not A or not B), therefore

```
(address is not null OR alternateAddress is not null)
```